# Firebase Analytics. Can not add custom parameter to event

Tags: events, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add a parameter to my event, but receiving an error "Internal error Please try again later".

I have no registered any parameter yet (0 text and 0 number). 
After pressing save button I receive following error messages

- Internal error. Please try again later. (in the center)
- One or more parameters have not been registered. Please try again (in the top right side)

Here is the steps...

1. Add the parameter

[image]

2. Select parameter type "Text"

[image]

3. After "Save" button click, I'm receiving fallowing error messages

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, and still not fixed for me, but as I see some people did a logout and cleared the cash, you can open the incognito Window instead of that, and check if it's fixed for you or not.
And if you got any solution, please write it here

Comment: I have the same issue... tried clearing cache, incognito window, disabling adblock extension...  Nothing works. I checked the network calls with developer tools and there's a call to `https://analytics.google.com/analytics/app/data/mobile/customparam` with the request body including the parameter I'm trying to add... the call returned a 500 status with literally this response body: `)]}',{"er":{"errorCode":13,"httpStatus":500}}` ... I'm posting this comment in case it can help someone else to find the right answer.

Comment: The error is actually means that the parameter limit is reached, Fire Base provides 10 text parameter and 40 numerical parameter per project, in my case I have created one project and in that project I have 5 variations for my app, if I want to add user_email parameter to 5 variations it's will be counted as 5 from 10 available text  parameters, so adding another text parameter will basically reach the limit. This is the Fire base analytics limitations. Instead I stated to use Crashlytics Events [link](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html), 3000 events, unlimited paramters

Answer (score 2):

The problem associated with Firebase configuration limits 10 text or 40 numeric parameters per PROJECT.

In the past, configuration limits for Firebase projects are enforced independently on each of the apps. Moving forward, Firebase will impose these configurations at the project level for future enhancements of the product.

So, you’re getting an Internal error message because you already reached the limit of 10 text or 40 numeric parameters per project. If you wish to add a text/numerical parameter, please do check the app (or other apps in the project) and delete some that are not active or irrelevant.
See this page for more information.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en

I know that the current message doesn’t tell that much, but I'm sure they will update it soon.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, [edit] the answer and tailor the post to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the next day. The website seems to get confused if you've recently added or removed some custom parameters.